# Get files not in hidden folders

Tags: python, os.walk

The test is failing because it's getting the files from hidden folders too. How can I modify the code so that it skips the hidden folders?

```
def get_files_not_in_hidden_folder(parent_folder: str, extension: str) -> List[str]:
    """
    Get all files recursively from parent folder,
    except for the ones that are in hidden folders
    """
    files = []
    for root, _, filenames in os.walk(parent_folder):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith(extension) and not root.startswith('.'):
                files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    logger.debug(f"get_files_not_in_hidden_folder: {parent_folder}, {extension} -> {files}")
    return files

def test_get_files_not_in_hidden_folder():
    Path('tmp').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    Path('tmp/test.json').touch()
    Path('tmp/tmp/.tmp').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    Path('tmp/tmp/.tmp/test.json').touch()
    Path('tmp/.tmp/tmp').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    Path('tmp/.tmp/tmp/test.json').touch()

    assert get_files_not_in_hidden_folder('tmp', '.json') == ['tmp/test.json']

    shutil.rmtree(Path('tmp'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you call `root` is the full path, including parent names.

If you want to convert to just the directory name, you can use `os.path.basename`,  like:

```
    for root, _, filenames in os.walk(parent_folder):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith(extension) and "/." not in root:
                files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Comment: This is the right start, but it could also be in a subdirectory of a hidden folder, e.g. `root == 'foo/.bar/baz'`

Comment: @Barmar thanks for spotting that.  my method was going to be a little dirty, so I thought to use a cleaner expression, but it introduced that logic error.  what do you think of my (dirty) solution now?

Comment: I was thinking of something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this something like as follows ...

```
def my_walk(root_dir):
    files,dirs = [],[]
    try:
        for fname in os.listdir(root_dir):
            if not fname.startswith("."):
               fpath = os.path.join(root_dir,fname)
               if os.path.isdir(fpath):
                  dirs.append(fpath)
               else:
                  files.append(fpath)
    except:
        print("SKIP:",root_dir)
    yield root_dir,dirs,files
    for d in dirs:
        yield from my_walk(d)
```

I think should work ...

```
for root, _, filenames in my_walk(parent_folder):
    print(f"{root} contains {filenames}")
```